# Is there a shortcut formula to complete a date time period marking? [new problem]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have a date and time table which look something like this:

***Table consist of date and time:***

[image]

If I wanted a period from 12/4/2019 (2pm onward) until 12/6/2019 5pm, to show the word "Done" on their cell while the rest just say "No". How should I do it?

The end product should be like this.

***End product table:***

[image]

Comment: Dates and times are just numbers for excel so you can add rows and columns headers and do a comparison with an IF statement

Comment: `=IF(AND(B$1+$A2>=DATE(2019,12,4)+TIME(14,0,0),B$1+$A2<=DATE(2019,12,6)+TIME(17,0,0)),"No","Done")`?

Comment: Thanks @gserg, work like a charm! Appreciate it!

Comment: You should not put [SOLVED] or [new problem] in the title, and you should not [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59495672/11683) as an answer. If your original problem is in fact not solved, which you realized only after accepting an answer, then please unaccept it and edit the question to clarify why it did not work. If you have a followup question, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula and drag and down then across right as needed.

```
=IF(AND(B$1+$A2>=DATE(2019,12,4)+TIME(14,0,0),B$1+$A2<=DATE(2019,12,6)+TIME(17,0,0)),"Done","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes! Harun! This work like a charm! Thanks for the time with this, appreciated it a lot!

Comment: Hi Harun! I have encountered another limitation. Do take a look at my new doubts below and appreciate it if you could provide me some solution to it.